# Is there an RSpec matcher to test the number of arguments with which a class is instantiated?

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec, tdd, rspec-expectations

Are there any matchers in RSpec to check that a class is instantiated with an argument?

Something like `it { is_expected.to respond_to(:initialize).with(1).argument }`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[The `respond_to` matcher that you give as an example exists, with the exact syntax that you give.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/respond-to-matcher)

However, you need to test the `.new` method, not the `.initialize` method, because `.initialize` is private.

```
class X
  def initialize(an_arg)
  end
end

describe X do
  describe '.new'
    it "takes one argument" do
      expect(X).to respond_to(:new).with(1).argument
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking? By default if the class requires arguments and you instantiate incorrectly it will throw an ArgumentError.

```
require 'rspec'

class Test
  def initialize(var)
  end
end

RSpec.describe do
  describe do
    it do
      expect(Test).to receive(:new).with('testing')
      Test.new('test')
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could use `attr_reader` on your arguments and compare `instance_variables`.